# Removing of the tabindex="-1" which is getting assigned by default from materialui v5

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the material-ui for dailog component.It has tabindex="-1" and i want to remove it completely.

```
<div class="MuiDialog-container MuiDialog-scrollPaper css-hz1bth-MuiDialog-container" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;">
```

so by default i am getting the tabindex as -1 from mui.Are there any ways for removing the tabindex="-1" which is getting applied by default.

Removing the tabindex="-1" completely.

Comment: May I ask why you want to remove the property?  Perhaps we can help you reach what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually when i am using nvda its reading the close button in this way "Modal title close dialog" "Modal title close heading" "close button heading level 2" "Modal title close dialog" "heading level 2 button close" .Its because of the focus which is moved there via a focus() call since that <div> has a tabindex="-1" '''<div role="presentation" tabindex="-1">''' so i thought of changing initial focus to the dialog itself rather the container above the dialog. This is the example of the code:https://codesandbox.io/s/somr32?file=/demo.tsx